# unable to extract image url in xml parsing in iphone

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing

I am quite new to the iphone development,
I am using xml parsing to parse contents of a feed

this feed contains this line

```
<enclosure url="http://www.abc.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/abc.jpg" length="64690" type="image/jpg" />
```

no I want to extract http://www.abc.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/abc.jpg

XML structure is like this

```
<item>
<title>ABC</title>

<description>asgafgfafdasf</description>

<enclosure url="http://www.abc.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/abc.jpg" length="64690" type="image/jpg" />

</item>
```

I got values corresponding to description and tile

but unable to  put down logic to parse that image url

CAn any bosy shed some light on this.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

url value (as well as length and type) is element's [attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Key_terminology). If you use NSXMLParser then in delegate's didStartElement method you can get it using: (you may also want to check if data is valid while retrieving it)

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
...
   if ([elementName equalsToString:@"enclosure"]){
      NSString* myUrl = [NSString stringWithString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
   }
...
}
```

Comment: What did you mentioned in the "parser did end element " and "found characters method"

Comment: @Warrior - you do not need them to get data from attribute

Comment: what i should do if enlosure tag is a child of another tag like <medi:group><enclosure url="http://www.abc.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/abc.jpg" length="64690" type="image/jpg" /></media group>.Then how could i retrieve its contents..please check my recent post...